# Bar Button Item fails to perform action Swift

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, button, uibarbuttonitem

I have a navigation bar (not a navigation controller nav bar). On the left I dragged a Bar Button Item and connected it to my view controller with an IBActon. The action performs:

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true).
```

Again, I have a navigation controller embedded into the hierarchy but I hide the navigation controllers navigation bar and use my own. Im not sure if that has something to do with it. But the Bar Button Items action is not being preformed consistently. Sometimes when I tap it the, view is popped (removed) and other times nothing happens at all. If anybody has experienced this and has any insight I would really appreciate it!

Relevant Code:

```
 @IBAction func backTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: add related code for this .

Comment: What is the frame for your bar button ? There is a common pitfall in bar buttons that sometimes they are way too small to tap. Especially if you are working on a device.

Comment: add debug point and check that method calling or not ?

Comment: I haven't set the frame for the bar button explicitly, just drag and drop into place on the storyboard. I don't believe its a size issue because not matter of the action is preformed or not I see the touch register. The only code that I have attached to the button I have edited into my question. Thanks for your replies!

Comment: @KKRocks how can I add a debug point? Like a breakpoint?

Comment: sorry it was breakpoint .

Comment: No worries... I'm not too familiar with using them so I'm gunna figure that out then report back! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I found the problem. It was the way I was segueing between view controllers. To navigation to around the application I am using

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Settings", bundle: nil)
    let viewControllerSettings = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsID") as! SettingsViewController
    self.show(viewControllerSettings, sender: self)
```

This however was the issue. To properly navigate to the new storyboard while maintaining a connection to the navigation controller in that storyboard you have to segue to the navigation controller itself. So it should be performed like:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Settings", bundle: nil)
    let viewControllerSettings = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsNavControllerID") as! UINavigationController
    self.show(viewControllerSettings, sender: self)
```

This way we have added a storyboardID to the navigation controller in the storyboard your segueing to and going through it. Without segueing through the navigation controller you can't perform

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true).
```

because the navigation controller wasn't loaded properly.